# How do you wait for input on the same Console.WriteLine() line?

Tags: c#

I want to pose a question such as:

> What is your name? Joe

How would I accomplish this using `Console.WriteLine` to also wait for the response on that same line instead of it being broken into:

> What is your name?
>
> Joe

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use [`Console.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0) instead, so there's no newline written:

```
Console.Write("What is your name? ");
var name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 22):

As Matt has said, use `Console.Write`. I would also recommend explicitly flushing the output, however - I believe `WriteLine` does this automatically, but I'd seen oddities when just using `Console.Write` and then waiting. So Matt's code becomes:

```
Console.Write("What is your name? ");
Console.Out.Flush();
var name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I've never used flush and never had any issues. While I don't discount your experience, I'd recommend against using Flush as a "just in case" helper - it adds unnecessary code.

Comment: Still, I'm glad Jon added this. I'd never have known to use Flush and it's good to have this here as a reference for when people do have problems.

Comment: I've only ever had to use flush when waiting for user input without using WriteLine. It may also be OS-dependent or even .NET-framework dependent. Given that I *have* seen it be an issue, I think it's wise to be cautious here.